# How to split long strings in pandas columns by punctuation

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a df that looks like this:

```
words                                              col_a   col_b  
I guess, because I have thought over that. Um,       1       0 
That? yeah.                                          1       1
I don't always think you're up to something.         0       1
```

I want to split df.words wherever a punctuation character is present `(.,?!:;)` into a separate row. However I want to preserve the col_b and col_b values from the original row for each new row. For example, the above df should look like this:

```
words                                              col_a   col_b  
I guess,                                             1       0
because I have thought over that.                    1       0
Um,                                                  1       0 
That?                                                1       1
yeah.                                                1       1
I don't always think you're up to something.         0       1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is using [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with the pattern `(.*?[.,?!:;])` to match any of these punctuation sings and the characters that preceed it (non greedy), and explode the resulting lists:

```
(df.assign(words=df.words.str.findall(r'(.*?[.,?!:;])'))
   .explode('words')
   .reset_index(drop=True))

                                          words  col_a  col_b
0                                      I guess,      1      0
1             because I have thought over that.      1      0
2                                           Um,      1      0
3                                         That?      1      1
4                                         yeah.      1      1
5  I don't always think you're up to something.      0      1
```

Comment: I was going to use `split` but this works (-:  Sorry, I mean to say that this is even better.